# How do I Install pillow on Raspberry pi pico?

Tags: pi-pico

I'm using Thonny to interface with my raspberry pi pico.  I went to `Tools->Manage packages...` and typed in pillow but I get an error about 13% into the installation that says:

```
Could not write next block after having written 269312 bytes to /lib/PIL/_imaging.cp37-win32.pyd
Make sure your device's filesystem has enough free space. (When overwriting a file, the old content may occupy space until the end of the operation.)


NB! Thonny could not execute 'upload'.
```

I'm assuming this is because I don't have enough space on my pi pico? Is there a smaller version of pillow that I can use or can I somehow add space to my pico?

I'm looking to run this demo on my pico https://github.com/waveshare/e-Paper/blob/master/RaspberryPi_JetsonNano/python/examples/epd_2in13_test.py

How can I run the example code above on my pi pico?

Comment: I tried to install ***Pillow 9.0*** to my Pico. The installation instruction says it does not look like a MicroPython package.  So I did't start.  But I found many other Pillow packages in the searching list. Perhaps you can try others.

Comment: I believe that the pico may not have enough storage for the full Pillow package.

Comment: (1)) Well, so you did see the "not like MicroPython package" but you ignored it and insisted to proceed installing, but got the "not enough space" error.  (2) I did not proceed because even I insisted to install it and found no problem installing, but I think sooner or later I will find another "not micropython" error.  Perhaps I might try it later, when I need Pillow again.

Comment: I skimmed your demo tutorial and found it only for Rpi Jetson Nano.  I know Jetson Nano is rich guy with loads of memory, but (2) it might not be fully compatible to Rpi Pico. (3) In other words, you would get incompatibility problem sooner or later.

Comment: Ah, I understand.  I was looking to do some image processing on the pico itself, but maybe that is an unrealistic goal due to the chip constraints.  Thank you for your insight.

Comment: You may be right.  I remember I ran Pillow on Rpi4B without any problem, and found it newbie friendly.  So I guess we need to wait for Pico to grow up.  Good luck and cheers.